# SSL with 2 pair Public/Private Key

Tags: java, security, ssl

I'm beginner in `SSL` protocol. I want connect my application to a server. Server get to me its`Certificate File` and wants my `Certificate File`. `Certificate` files are self-signed. My application developed by `Java` and server application developed by `C`. Server `Certificate` created by `OpenSSL`.

I have  `private/public` that is my self and server `certificate` file now.

I don't know what do I? I trying some day but don't get any result.

(Sorry if I am using the wrong terminology or grammar, I am learning english language.)

**Edited**

I research in web and found I must research for `two-way SSL authentication by java` Anyone have more information?

Comment: So, in other words, you want to know how you can use these certificates to secure the client-server connection?  Is that it?

Comment: You need to read the JSSE Reference Guide.

Comment: @Hugo yes,you are right.

Comment: @EJP I read it, but don't know what do.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to use an OpenSSL implementation for both the client and the server.
The protocol is standard, so you can use any implementation on each side.

Have a look at the client example here (in java):
http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php

Standard java classes are used, so you can also use this as a starting point to know what javadocs to start reading! ;)

As for client side, you can use openssl (it's a lib too).  I've never donde SSL on C, so I can't help you there.

Generally, you'll treat the sslsocket the same way you'd treat an ordinary tcp socket. :)

---

As a side note, you *may* be interseted on using HTTPS, instead of raw SSL, depending on your application (just saying; you might want to consider it).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly; but seems that your client is not able to connect to your server. You need to import your server certificate in a client truststore. Since your client is a java application you need your truststore in the java compatible PKCS format. Get help on creating a trustore using java Keytool utility. Since your server side is C application you need to create a C compatible truststore for the server side. You can do it by simply copying the PEM representation of the certificate into a file (cat server.crt > truststore.pem) to be used as the truststore. Since your certificates are self signed, copying just the endorsing authority's certificate ( which in your case is the server certificate itself) is sufficient. Configure your client and server to use their respective truststore and it should work.

Comment: You don't need the PKCS11 format, you can use the JKS format.